# ICO won't render from _layouts in IE 8

Tags: 2013

I have an ICO file located in the layouts/images folder. This renders properly in Chrome but not in IE 8. Is this a SharePoint limitation?

```
/_layouts/15/CustomImages/snFavicon.ico
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an issue with IE 8.

Better to covert that file to another format.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1439232/ie-doesnt-show-ico-icons-in-html-if-not-served-as-image-x-icon

Comment: Converted to PNG and it renders fine. ty